# iOS - Keyboard won't show

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield

This is a bit of a strange error.

I have a log-in screen which accepts a username and password inside two `UITableViewCells`.  When the app first loads, this screen works fine.

It loads another screen which allows a user to log-out - this reloads the original screen and the user is capable of logging in again (or with a different username and password).

If the user logs out *again*, the original screen presents itself but the `UITextFields` associated with the username and password *will not work*.  `textFieldDidBeginEditing` is not called - even though it was successfully called on the previous two attempts.

The "loading screen" .XIB file is loaded fresh each time - so I simply don't understand why the third time would cause problems?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Are you doing anything with your window when switching views, i.e., showing a loading view in an alert-level window? If another window has keyWindow status, you'll likely run into trouble with your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

It is look like timing issue to me. It may happen while changing(transition) the views. Some how your textfield can not be the first responder.

I would check who is the first responder?

Can you try call resignFirstResponder for the view which is responsible for logging out, just before logging out.

Another problem may be you finger does not touch exactly on text field but table view cell.

Did you implement the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: ?